# Intellij groovy "assignments with incompatible types"

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, groovy, spring-data-jpa

I'm experiencing an issue with IntelliJ where it shows the following error in many of my groovy test files:

```
'save' in 'org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository<testmodule.TestEntity,java.lang.Long>' cannot be applied to '(testmodule.TestEntity)' less... (Ctrl+F1)  This inspection reports assignments with incompatible types
```

I can reproduce the issue with the following classes:

**entity**:

```
package testmodule;

public class TestEntity {
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

**repository**:

```
package testmodule;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface TestEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<TestEntity, Long> {
}
```

**spock test**:

```
package testmodule

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired

class TestEntityRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    TestEntityRepository testEntityRepository

    def "should save testEntity"() {
        given:
        final testEntity = new TestEntity()

        when:
        final saved = testEntityRepository.save(testEntity)
    }
}
```

when I hover over `testEntity` in the test I get the above message. Please see image attached:

[image]

Comment: What version of IntelliJ IDEA you use? I reproduced same classes as you have shown and IDEA 2017.2.6 does not complain with such warning.

Comment: @SzymonStepniak I'm using 2017.3.2 Ultimate Edition.

Comment: I've reported an issue, you could vote/follow: [IDEA-184877](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-184877)

Comment: Thanks @Andrey! So this is a regression from previous versions of Intellij? How do I vote for an issue in Youtrack?

Comment: Looks like a regression. See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241135 if you are not familiar with YouTrack.

Answer (score 0):

I solved similar issue in ItellijIDEA by File -> Invalidate caches / Restart.